# Schematron - test if an attribute exists and if it does verify correct spelling of that attribute value

Tags: schematron

trying to figure out how to test if optional attributes do exist in a document, they can only contain one of two values and those values must be spelled correctly.

Here's an example of the XML:

```
<SIGNOFF ID="S0001" SIGN-ALL="YES">
  <ACCOMPBY ID="JCAT0001" INPUT-LABEL-REFS="IL00001 IL00002 IL00003" QUAL-REQS="RVPSM"/>
  <INSPBY ID="JCIT0001" NAFLAG="YES" USERINPUT="NO" USELATESTREV="YES" QUAL-REQS="LLM"/>
  <BUYBACK ID="JCBT0001"/>
</SIGNOFF>
```

Here's my Schematron test that's failing:

```
<rule context="ACCOMPBY/@QUALS-REQS">
  <assert test="@QUAL-REQS = 'RVSM' or @QUAL-REQS = 'LLM'" role="error" id="warn_signoff_accompby">SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY @QUALS-REQS values RVSM or LLM are misspelled</assert>
</rule>

<rule context="INSPBY/@QUALS-REQS">
      <assert test="@QUAL-REQS = 'RVSM' or @QUAL-REQS = 'LLM'" role="error" id="warn_signoff_accompby">SIGNOFF/INSPBY @QUALS-REQS values RVSM or LLM are misspelled</assert>
</rule>
```

Have also tried this but it hits on every SIGNOFF whether the attribute is present or not:

```
<rule context="SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY">
      <assert test="(@QUAL-REQS = 'RVSM' or @QUAL-REQS = 'LLM')" role="error" id="warn_signoff_accompby">SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY qualifications RVSM or LLM are misspelled</assert>
</rule>

<rule context="SIGNOFF/INSPBY">
      <assert test="(@QUAL-REQS = 'RVSM' or @QUAL-REQS = 'LLM')" role="error" id="warn_signoff_accompby">SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY qualifications RVSM or LLM are misspelled</assert>
</rule>
```

So if the Schematron worked correctly on the above XML example it would flag the user that ACCOMPBY/@QUALS-REQS value is spelled incorrectly.

Is this doable? Thank you so much for any point in the right direction.

Comment: In the first try the context is the attribute node so the comparisons in the `assert test` should use e.g. `. = 'RVSM'`.

Comment: Did the answer not help?

Comment: Hi Martin, apologizes in my delay getting back to you, was in the hospital with a kidney stone and pancreatitis but back at work today. I just tested again and its still hitting on every SIGNOFF in the document whether @QUAL-REQS is present or not. Its almost like we need an IF statement, if this attribute is present enforce this rule.  If its not then ignore. Feel like I should of provided more examples/scenarios.

Comment: Which tool do you use to do the Schematron validation? As I have pointed out in the answer, for me with the Schematron fiddle that uses Schxslt under the hood, for the sample data only a single `svrl:failed-assert location="/Q{}SIGNOFF[1]/Q{}ACCOMPBY[1]"` is found. Of course you could also change the context to check for the attribute with a predicate e.g. `<rule context="SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY[@QUAL-REQS]"><assert test="(@QUAL-REQS = 'RVSM' or @QUAL-REQS = 'LLM')" role="error" id="warn_signoff_accompby">SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY qualifications RVSM or LLM are misspelled</assert></rule>`

Comment: Hi Martin - using Oxygen and it looks like this is the one that works!! `<rule context="SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY[@QUAL-REQS]"><assert test="(@QUAL-REQS = 'RVSM' or @QUAL-REQS = 'LLM')" role="error" id="warn_signoff_accompby">SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY qualifications RVSM or LLM are misspelled</assert></rule>`

Comment: Its hitting on all the SIGNOFFS that have a misspelled entry in ACCOMPBY or INSPBY QUAL-REQS. It's also ignoring correctly spelled QUAL-REQS entries and SIGNOFFS that do not contain ACCOMPBY or INSPBY QUAL-REQS. Thank you so very, very much for your time and patience :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use your sample XML document

```
<SIGNOFF ID="S0001" SIGN-ALL="YES">
  <ACCOMPBY ID="JCAT0001" INPUT-LABEL-REFS="IL00001 IL00002 IL00003" QUAL-REQS="RVPSM"/>
  <INSPBY ID="JCIT0001" NAFLAG="YES" USERINPUT="NO" USELATESTREV="YES" QUAL-REQS="LLM"/>
  <BUYBACK ID="JCBT0001"/>
</SIGNOFF>
```

with the schematron schema (basically the second attempt you showed put into a complete schema)

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt3">
    <pattern>
      <rule context="SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY">
            <assert test="(@QUAL-REQS = 'RVSM' or @QUAL-REQS = 'LLM')" role="error" id="warn_signoff_accompby">SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY qualifications RVSM or LLM are misspelled</assert>
      </rule>
      
      <rule context="SIGNOFF/INSPBY">
            <assert test="(@QUAL-REQS = 'RVSM' or @QUAL-REQS = 'LLM')" role="error" id="warn_signoff_accompby">SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY qualifications RVSM or LLM are misspelled</assert>
      </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>
```

at https://martin-honnen.github.io/schematron-fiddle/

I get

```
   <svrl:failed-assert location="/Q{}SIGNOFF[1]/Q{}ACCOMPBY[1]" role="error" id="warn_signoff_accompby" test="(@QUAL-REQS = 'RVSM' or @QUAL-REQS = 'LLM')">
      <svrl:text>SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY qualifications RVSM or LLM are misspelled</svrl:text>
   </svrl:failed-assert>
```

That seems to be your wanted and intended result.

If you want to explicitly express in the context that the attribute exists you could also change the context to check for the attribute with a predicate e.g.

```
<rule context="SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY[@QUAL-REQS]"><assert test="(@QUAL-REQS = 'RVSM' or @QUAL-REQS = 'LLM')" role="error" id="warn_signoff_accompby">SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY qualifications RVSM or LLM are misspelled</assert></rule>
```